# CruiseControl.NET (CCNET) "Process exited event received" but build waits?

Tags: c#, wpf, cruisecontrol.net, exit-code, ccnet-config

I'm using CCNET to schedule and run some automated testing. I have a few executables I want to run. These are developed in C#/WPF. I'm exiting out of the app using an exit code "Shutdown(0);".

CC runs the application, the applications completes then shuts down, CC console shows "Process exited event received" but appears to continue waiting for the application to exit.

How can I get CC to consider the task complete and move on to the next task?
I have added 0 in successExitCodes and set unlimited timeout with 0 in buildTimeoutSeconds.

Comment: Are you able to see if the windows process for the c# app has actually exited? i.e. via task manager.

Comment: Yes I could see it had exited and the console picked up the exit. I have found the issue - the process started another process which it didn't kill before exiting. CCNET was waiting until that child process also exited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and resolved the problem.

The process I ran through the executable task had started another process and not killed it before exiting. CCNET was waiting for that child process to also exit.